# Attempt to de-reference a null object error on User-Input Form

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

**UPDATE**

Update to my Apex

```
public with sharing class ShouldShowSHSection{
    public ShouldShowSHSection(ApexPages.StandardController paramController) {
       Intake = paramController;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController Intake {get; set;}
    public Boolean getShouldShowSHSection() {
       Intake__c record = new Intake__c();
          if(
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c == 'Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom' && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null
            ) 
            {
            return true;
            }
        
          if(
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null
            )  
            {
            return true;
            }
        
            if(
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null
            )  
            {
            return true;
            }
          
          if(
            record.Safety_Concerns__c != null && record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null
            )  
            {
            return true;
            }
        
          if(
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null
            )  
            {
            return true;
            }
        
            if(
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null
            )  
            {
            return true;
            }
        
        
            if(
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null
            )  
            {
            return true;
            }
        
        
            if(
            record.Safety_Concerns__c != null && record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') && (
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') ||
            record.Safety_Concerns__c != null && record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') ||
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair')
            )
            )  
            {
            return true;
            }
        
        
            if(
            record.Safety_Concerns__c != null && record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Wandering or Elopement/Running Way or Egress (Leaving the Home)') && (
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') ||
            record.Safety_Concerns__c != null && record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') ||
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair')
            )
            )  
            {
            return true;
            }
        
            if(
            record.Safety_Concerns__c != null && record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Confusion or Dementia') && (
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') ||
            record.Safety_Concerns__c != null && record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') ||
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair')
            )
            )  
            {
            return true;
            }
        
            if(
            record.Safety_Concerns__c != null && record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Accessing Help for an Emergency') && (
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') ||
            record.Safety_Concerns__c != null && record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') ||
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair')
            )
            )  
            {
            return true;
            }
        
            if(
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Walking or Mobility') && (
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') ||
            record.Safety_Concerns__c != null && record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') ||
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair')
            )
            )  
            {
            return true;
            }
        
            if(
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair') && (
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c == null ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') ||
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') ||
            record.Safety_Concerns__c != null && record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') ||
            record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') ||
            record.Physical_Concerns__c != null && record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair')
            )
            )  
            {
            return true;
            }
        
          return false;
        }
        
        }
```

I no longer get the null object error on load.  However, if I choose selections within Personal Care for toileting and bathing and within Physical Concerns for environmental controls, I would think my pageblock section should appear based on my Apex - What am I still missing?

---

UPDATE

Here is the update to my Apex

```
public with sharing class ShouldShowSHSection {
public ApexPages.StandardController Intake {get; set;}
public ShouldShowSHSection(ApexPages.StandardController paramController) {
        Intake = paramController; }
public Boolean getShouldShowSHSection() {
       Intake__c record = (Intake__c)this.Intake.getRecord();
```

I am still getting the "Attempt to de-reference a null object" error. This happens when attempting to load the page.

---

I'm using a controller extension on a user-input visualforce form to call a method that shows a section only if certain values from picklists are selected.  I'm getting the error "Attempt to de-reference a null object error", and I'm not sure why or how to fix it.  How can I address this, please?

Here is my VF Code

```
<apex:page standardController="Intake__c" extensions="IntakeExtension, ShouldShowSHSection" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    
 
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.styleForIntake}"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   
  
  
<body>
<!-- multistep form -->
<apex:form Id="msform" styleClass="form">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <br></br><br></br>
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Client Info</li>
    <li>Residence </li>
    <li>Concerns </li>
    <li>Tech Comfort</li>
    <li>Recommendation</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
 <br></br><br></br>
   <fieldset>
   <br></br><br></br>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Client Information</h2> 
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Here, we will gather information specific to the client.</h3> <br></br>
   
    <br></br> <br></br><br></br> <br></br>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset >
    
    
   <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Residence Information</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Here we will ask for information on the residence where the technology will be used.</h3>
    <br></br> <br></br>

    
    <br></br> <br></br><br></br> <br></br>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
     
     

    <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Concerns Addressed</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Please select all client concerns to be addressed.</h3>
    <br></br> <br></br>
    <p>  
        Personal Care Concerns:
     </p>
    <div class="selectiondiv">
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblockSection >
                <apex:inputField styleClass="fieldset" value="{!Intake__c.Personal_Care__c}">
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="technologyRecommendation"/>
                </apex:inputField>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </div>
    <br></br> <br></br>
    <p>  
        Safety Concerns:
     </p>
    <div class="selectiondiv">
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblockSection >
                <apex:inputField styleClass="fieldset" value="{!Intake__c.Safety_Concerns__c}">
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="technologyRecommendation"/>
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="SHRec"/>
                </apex:inputField>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </div>
    <br></br> <br></br>
    
      <p>  
        Physical Concerns:
     </p>
    <div class="selectiondiv">
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblockSection >
                <apex:inputField styleClass="fieldset" value="{!Intake__c.Physical_Concerns__c}">
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="technologyRecommendation"/>
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="SHRec"/>
                </apex:inputField>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </div>
    
    <br> </br><br></br>
    
    
    <p>  
        Social Concerns:
     </p>
    <div class="selectiondiv">
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblockSection >
                <apex:inputField styleClass="fieldset" value="{!Intake__c.Social_Concerns__c}">
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="technologyRecommendation"/>
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="SHRec"/>
                </apex:inputField>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </div>
    
     <p>  
        Other outcomes or routines noted on the ISP/support plan that should be considered:
     </p>
     <apex:inputField styleClass="fieldset" value="{!Intake__c.Other_Outcomes__c}"> </apex:inputField> <br> </br>
     
    
    
    <br></br> <br></br><br></br> <br></br>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
     </fieldset>
     
     
     
               <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Level of Comfort with Technology</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Here we will ask questions regarding the client's current level of comfortablity with technoloogy.</h3>
    <br></br> <br></br>
    
    
    <br></br> <br></br><br></br> <br></br>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
     </fieldset>
     
     
     
  
      <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Technology Recommendation</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Based on your selections for 'Concerns Addressed', we recommend the following technology:</h3>
           
           <apex:pageblock id="seizures">
               <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Intake__c.Population__c, 'Epilepsy/Seizures'), 'true', 'false')}" value="We do not currently support Epilepsy/Seizure-detecting technology."/> <br/>
               <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Intake__c.Population__c, 'Epilepsy/Seizures'), 'true', 'false')}" value="However, we may be able to assist with additionally noted concerns."/>
           </apex:pageblock>
           
           <apex:pageblock id="technologyRecommendation">
           
           
            <apex:pageblockSection rendered="{!shouldShowSHSection}">
                    <apex:outputText value="SH System Recommendation"/>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
          
      
        </apex:pageblock>
    <br></br> <br></br><br></br> <br></br>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />

    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" styleClass="submit action-button" style="width=100px" value="Submit" id="saveButton" />
     </fieldset>
      
    
 
</apex:form>

<script>
//jQuery time






var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; 
var left, opacity, scale; 
var animating; 





$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
    
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
    
    next_fs.show(); 
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
    
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
    
    previous_fs.show(); 
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
     
    });
});




$(document).ready(function () {
$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: "-100:+0"
});

});


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: "-100:+0"
});

});

</script>



</body>
</apex:page>
```

Here is my controller code

```
public with sharing class ShouldShowSHSection {
    public ApexPages.StandardController Intake {get; set;}

    public Boolean getShouldShowSHSection() {
       Intake__c record = (Intake__c)this.Intake.getRecord();
  if(
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') && !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)')
    ) 
    {
    return true;
    }

  if(
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') && !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)')
    )  
    {
    return true;
    }

    if(
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') && !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)')
    )  
    {
    return true;
    }
  
  if(
    record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') && !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)')
    )  
    {
    return true;
    }

  if(
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') && !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)')
    )  
    {
    return true;
    }

    if(
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') && !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)')
    )  
    {
    return true;
    }


    if(
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') && !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)')
    )  
    {
    return true;
    }


    if(
    record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') && (
    !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') ||
    record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') ||
    record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair')
    )
    )  
    {
    return true;
    }


    if(
    record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Wandering or Elopement/Running Way or Egress (Leaving the Home)') && (
    !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') ||
    record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') ||
    record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair')
    )
    )  
    {
    return true;
    }

    if(
    record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Confusion or Dementia') && (
    !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') ||
    record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') ||
    record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair')
    )
    )  
    {
    return true;
    }

    if(
    record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Accessing Help for an Emergency') && (
    !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') ||
    record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') ||
    record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair')
    )
    )  
    {
    return true;
    }

    if(
    record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Walking or Mobility') && (
    !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') ||
    record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') ||
    record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair')
    )
    )  
    {
    return true;
    }

    if(
    record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair') && (
    !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Sleeping Routines/Up and About at Night') ||
    record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Completing Daily Living Routines with Auditory Prompts like Laundry/Cooking/Cleaning') ||
    record.Safety_Concerns__c.contains('Cooking Safety/Meal Prep') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Social Connection with Friends and Family') ||
    record.Social_Concerns__c.contains('Using Tech for Entertainment (smart speakers/social media)') ||
    record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Getting in or Out of Bed or Chair')
    )
    )  
    {
    return true;
    }

  return false;
}

}
```

Comment: Did you omit the constructor of the class on purpose while pasting it here or you don't have it in your code?

Comment: @SergioAlcocer - I'm not exactly sure what that is, so I must not have it.  Can you explain what that should be?

Comment: Is 'public with sharing class ShouldShowSHSection ' not the constructor here? I'm a little lost on next steps

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe when you get the error.  When you load the page or when you do a specific action?

Comment: @DavidCheng - This error occurs on load of the page -  I will edit the question to reflect this

Comment: Please refer to [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) to get a clearer idea of what @DavidCheng is suggesting. You can also take a look at this example [here](http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2015/03/standard-controller-extension-and.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are declaring `ShouldShowSHSection` to be your Extension in the visualforce,

> `... extensions="IntakeExtension, ShouldShowSHSection" ...`

however in your apex class you are not having the proper handling of the StandardController.

Try storing the value of Intake on the constructor first. Add the following constructor to your class

```
    public ShouldShowSHSection(ApexPages.StandardController paramController) {
        Intake = paramController;
    }
```

And let me know if it worked

Comment: I am still getting the error for null object - I have added an update to the Apex at the top of my original posting, showing your suggested change.

Comment: Make sure that none of the fields are null before doing a .contains. I also suggest you to encapsulate all your code in a try-catch and to add errors to the page so it is easier for you to debug where you are getting the null

Comment: This is a user-filled form, so all fields will be null until the user enters a selection - Is it possible to make this work with their chosen inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call methods on a null object. Consider:

```
Account record = new Account();
if(record.Name.contains('Hello')) {
  System.debug('The name contains Hello.');
}
```

This will obviously result in a System.NullPointerException. Similarly, you must check with `contains` until you first check to make sure it's not null.

```
if(
record.Social_Concerns__c != null && record.Social_Concerns__c
  .contains('Having Privacy or Being Alone Part or All of Day or Night') && !record.Physical_Concerns__c.contains('Controlling Environment with Limited Mobility (turning on lights/opening doors)')
```

Comment: Please see latest update in my edited question - I no longer get the null object error on load.  However, if I choose selections within Personal Care for toileting and bathing and within Physical Concerns for environmental controls, I would think my pageblock section should appear based on my Apex - What am I still missing?